# Extracting most recent date from VARCHAR2

Tags: sql, oracle

Data:

```
USER_ID    VIOLATION_DATES
--------------------------------
1          18-Jul-21 > 24-Jul-21 
2          05-Aug-21
3          09-Jun-21
1          18-Jul-21
```

I have a table that has columns for Users and their dates of violations. I want to extract the most recent violation for each user.

This is the query I've written:

```
select 
    USR_ID,    
    max(to_date(VIOLATION_DATES, 'DD-MON-YY')) as Most_Recent_VIOLATIONS
from 
    table
group by 
    USR_ID
```

However I get this error:

> ORA-01830: date format picture ends before converting entire input string

I believe it has something to do with the way the most recent violation is appended (18-Jul-21 > 24-Jul-21 ). Can anyone provide any clarity on how I can extract the most recent date for each user? for example:

```
USER_ID    VIOLATION_DATES
--------------------------
1          24-Jul-21 
2          05-Aug-21
3          09-Jun-21
```

I understand that this storage method isn't ideal but this is out of my control.

Comment: This is a terrible storage format. You should be using datetime fields and storing the from and to dates in separate columns. Your query would be trivial if the data was stored correctly.

Comment: Anyway I guess you could get the rightmost 9 characters and then feed those to the to_date function

Comment: ugh. yes terrible.  so terrible that you should change the design.. keeping it as is, then you should look at REGEX to parse first then try your max logic

Comment: You should force whoever is responsible for this horrible design to implement that query for you. That will teach him/her.

Comment: What version of Oracle are you using? If it is a recent version, you could use `ON CONVERSION ERROR` to ignore items that don't match the date format

Comment: I'd start by treating the `violation_dates` column as a CSV list and splitting the row into two (or more). Then you could do a `group by` query over the result.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the multi-value string into separate rows, then "group by" as normal (the `with` clause is just to provide test data - substitute your actual table):

```
with demo (user_id, violation_dates) as
     ( select 1, '18-Jul-21 > 24-Jul-21' from dual union all
       select 2, '05-Aug-21' from dual union all
       select 3, '09-Jun-21' from dual union all
       select 1, '18-Jul-21' from dual )
select user_id
     , max(to_date(regexp_substr(d.violation_dates, '[^> ]+', 1, r.rn) default null on conversion error,'DD-MON-YY')) as violation_date
from   demo d
       cross apply
             ( select rownum as rn
               from dual connect by rownum <= regexp_count(d.violation_dates,'>') +1 ) r
group by user_id
order by 1;
```

"default null on conversion error" requires Oracle 12.2.